# error 500 image base64

Tags: php, bitmap, xampp, base64

Good day to all, it's my first time to post here.

I want to upload an image in my domain using an image that is encoded to base64,
my image was completely uploaded to the server, but I'm still getting an **server error 500**,
The memory_limit at my php.ini file is 128M`
I'm using XAMPP server

```
    <?php

header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

$encoded_string = $_POST['string_encoded']; //encoded string

$imagename = 'image.png';

$decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

$path = 'imageses/'.$imagename;

$file = fopen($path, 'wb');

fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
fclose($file);

?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose image.png has a size of 2MB. In this case, only decoding it from base64 will write roughly 64 * 2 MB into memory, which is 128 MB. This could be the a cause of the issue. To fix it, increase `memory_limit` in your php.ini. Another possible problem can be that a script is loaded several times, doing the same large decoding in parallel manner. If everything fails, then you can still achieve success, but not decoding the whole file, only one smaller packet at a time and forgetting the packet when calculated as soon as possible.

Comment: I tried to make the memory_limit=512M at the php.ini and then save it, but the output is still the same, I just delete the $_POST method and input a encoded string default value in it, it always show me the same error

Comment: @MarkDylanBMercado what is the size of your file?

Comment: It's an png image file that only have 5.57 kb file size.

Comment: How many requests are sent to the server in the same time at server peaks?

Comment: It's just that's the only script i run and replace the $_POST['string_encoded'] with the encoded base 64 string of the image. :)

Comment: @MarkDylanBMercado if you comment out the line of $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string); and write $decoded_string = ''; instead, is the problem still happening? (checking whether the problem is what we think it is)

Comment: yeah it is happening :D, but the image didn't save so that means the problem is not the base64 ? The problem here is the writing of file ? how can I fix that ? thanks :)

Comment: @MarkDylanBMercado try to comment out parts of your code gradually until the problem is no longer happening. This way you will be able to localize where the problem is.